# How to get rank using mysql query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have the following code, and I would like to get only the league rank of the user based on his total balance. How can I do this?

```
// Set League Rank by User
global $post;
$post_author = $post->post_author;
$post_status = 'publish';
$meta_key = 'balance';
$rank = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
    "
    SELECT *, @rownum := @rownum + 1 from
    (
    SELECT 
        SUM(meta_value) as balance, 
    FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
    JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r;
    WHERE pm.meta_key = %s AND p.post_author = %s AND p.post_status = %s
    order by balance desc)x, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    ",
    $meta_key, $post_author, $post_status
    ) );
```

Can some help me?

Thank you.

Comment: can you post a table definition for the two tables in question?

Comment: where are you setting $meta_key

Comment: this code works well to retrieve the balance of every user. what I need is to get the ranking, which is a column that doesn't exist in the tables.

Comment: you are ranking on basis off?

Comment: the balance of every player

Comment: Can you please describe what do you mean by "rank" if there's no such column?

Comment: get the position of the player based on his balance. So the player with the highest balance his ranked 1 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
SELECT 
    ROUND (SUM(meta_value),2) as balance, 
    @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS rank
FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r;
WHERE pm.meta_key = %s AND p.post_author = %s AND p.post_status = %s
order by balance desc
```

I might misunderstood what do you mean by rank so if this doesn't work, please explain further what exactly do you need.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately I tried it and it doesn't work. What I mean is a league table where the user with the highest balance is the one ranked 1st and so on. The balance sorts the rank of each user.

Comment: I have updated the code above to see if I can illustrate better what I need.